# SSMS 17.5 Not showing ellipse when cell data is larger than available display area

Tags: windows, ssms

I noticed an issue with Sql Server Management Studio 17.5 (maybe other versions too) where the ellipse (indicates a cell has more data than what it shown) is missing.  It is problematic when dealing with ID columns since there is no indication that there is more data than what is being displayed.

Here's some screen shots

Problematic Data

[image: Problematic Data]

Actual Data

[image: Actual Data]

Ideally, the first screen shot would show an ellipse after the first digit, but instead it shows as if the cell is displaying its complete contents.  Has anyone else found this to be an issue, and did you find any work arounds?  There was nothing available in the Tools->Options menu.

Edit:
I found the same behavior in Windows 10 Windows Explorer.  Would this type of thing be a registry setting?  Maybe it's being shared between Windows and SSMS
[image: Windows Exploer Filename/Extension Truncation]

Comment: I found this was an issue for me too. I was looking at a table my coworker had created. I had thought that he did not make a column unique and it had bad data. Turns out the data was truncated like your example above. Very misleading without the ellipsis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in Windows build 1803

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/filename-truncate-bug/d447a633-7f1d-4d90-a282-0e2ccbab8d04

With a newer version it has been fixed.

I've confirmed it in both SSMS and Windows Explorer, and I cannot reproduce the above examples.